# Loop not recognizing statement

Tags: c#, arrays

So I'm working on this dice game for school but I've stumbled upon this problem:
First, let me give some context.
I have an array called `diceResults[]` in which the amount of thrown dice is saved in the array (i.e. you rolled two one's, so the first index of the array is 2)

Now One pair, Two pair, Three of a kind and Full house are all working fine.
But when a Full house is rolled it recognizes a pair, three of a kind, and a full house. But it doesn't recognize the second pair in the three of a kind.
I've tried several solutions but none seem to work.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < diceResults.Length; i++)
        {
            if (diceResults[i] == 2)
            {
                onePair = true;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < diceResults.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (diceResults[j] == 2 || diceResults[j] == 3)
                    {
                        twoPair = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < diceResults.Length; i++)
        {
            if (diceResults[i] == 3)
            {
                threeKind = true;
                for (int k = 0; k < diceResults.Length; k++)
                {
                    if (diceResults[k] == 2)
                    {
                        fullHouse = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've tried setting 2 different `if` statements containing `(diceResults[j] == 2)` and `(diceResults[j] == 3)` in below each-other too, but this didn't seem to work either.

I'm checking what values are set using the following method.

```
 private void CheckBoolValues()
    {
        if (onePair == true)
            MessageBox.Show("pair yes");
        if (twoPair == true)
            MessageBox.Show("2 pair yes");
        if (threeKind == true)
            MessageBox.Show("3 of a kind yes");
        if (fourKind == true)
            MessageBox.Show("4 of a kind yes");
        if (yahtzee == true)
            MessageBox.Show("yahtzee yes");
        if (lowStraight == true)
            MessageBox.Show("lowstraight yes");
        if (highStraight == true)
            MessageBox.Show("high straight yes");
        if (fullHouse == true)
            MessageBox.Show("full house yes");
    }
```

Would appreciate some help!

Comment: you need to show a bit more code in regards to your variables being set to true or false, also what do you do after the loop where are you breaking from the code when a condition is met..? did you use the debugger to step thru the code..? or did you just code it and run it..?

Comment: You need to check if `k != i` or you will always get true for fullHouse, edit: sorry, that is not correct. you are explicitly checking for `== 2`. My comment is not correct

Comment: Suggestion: You can check for fullHouse by doing `fullHouse = twoPair && threeKind`, can't you?

Comment: ...this is assuming that you are rollin 5 die in total

Comment: Yes I'm rolling 5 dice, I'll try checking for a full house like you suggested now. I just cant figure out why it doesn't find the second pair or three of a kind after the fist pair when a full house is rolled.

Comment: I can't find a question in this question. You wrote some code, it's wrong, you don't know how to write the code correctly, and you're trying random stuff and hoping that it will work. That's not a question. Nor is it a good technique for solving a problem. What's your question?

Comment: My question is why does it skip over the 2nd pair if a full house is found. I'm asking for clarification of the flow, so i can actually understand whats wrong here.

Comment: I dont think you can use this loop try use List to find it. You cant use the magic code that we dont know what is `2` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't your first few lines of code be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < diceResults.Length; i++)
{
      if ((diceResults[i] == 2) || (diceResults[i] == 3))
      {
           onePair = true;
           ...
```

Comment: ^ this was exactly the answer i was looking for, i thank you, i totally forgot that when looking for a pair, i should also accept a three or a kind!

Comment: then maybe you should mark the answer as an useful answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you roll 3 1s and 2 2s, you'll never detect the "second pair", because first loop only looks at dice totals over 2. But it's correct to set `twoPair = true` at the point you set `fullHouse = true`. Also you don't actually needed a nested loop to implement this.

BTW I'm not sure what the rules of Yahtzee are, but is 4 of a kind considered "two pairs"?

Comment: Thank you, I suppose adding     twoPair = true to the Full house loop is sufficient, therefore my question is unrelevant now.

Comment: Not irrelevant, just answered :-) If your happy with the answer it's good stackoverflow netiquette to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I personaly see no sense you want to detect a pair in a three of a kind but anyways. You could just check if there's already a pair of two in the results like this. Also doing multiple for-loops would be kind of superfluous.

```
    bool onePair = false;
    bool twoPair = false;
    bool threeKind = false;
    bool fullHouse = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < diceResults.Length; i++)
    {
        if (diceResults[i] >= 2)
        {
            if(onePair == true) {
                twoPair = true;
            }
            onePair = true;
        }
        if (diceResults[i] >= 3)
        {
            threeKind = true;
            for (int j = 0; j< diceResults.Length; j++)
            {
                if (diceResults[k] == 2)
                {
                    fullHouse = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The sense is that the user still needs to have the option to select the pair our of the three of a kind if for example the user already completed the three of a kind